# How do I tell a headless Ubuntu 14.04 server how to access a shared drive that is on Windows domain and renew password for a Windows user?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, networking, server-message-block

Inside a corporate situation, the machines are largely controlled using Microsoft technology.

I have another server on the same network that is running Ubuntu 14.04 **headless**. No GUI.

I want to write a script inside the Ubuntu headless so that it can access the Windows shared drive.

I also have the username and password of a valid Windows user who can access the shared drive.

This set of credentials has been approved to be used exclusively for this Ubuntu machine.

I believe I should use smbclient to do that.

My two questions are:

1. what are the commands to access a shared drive?
2. how do I reset the password of the Windows user since there is a company policy of changing the password every 3 months?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `mount` command. [`man mount.cifs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) is the easiest, the share will become part of the Linux file system. The alternative is `smbclient` a FTP like interface.
2. Most password policies have an exception for *service accounts* allowing for passwords that don't expire.

Comment: Sadly, the company that contracted me is one of those large byzantine organizations. I am dealing with the in-house IT team which is servicing my client from another country. They insist out of policy that my server needs to be assigned a user account. My contact person is getting an additional user account just for this reason. Hence my contact person will have 2 user accounts for himself. Weird I know.